# transfer weights across separated Meshes?

Tags: mesh, armature

Not sure how else to phrase this question. and maybe Im not understanding Transfer weights.

My issue is i have this model
[image]

I have the armature automatically weighted across each individual mesh, but Im trying copy the weights from where the meshes connect at intersecting vertices.

As you can see with this closer image, the intersecting points don't have the same weights and its causing the mesh to deform incorrectly.
[image]

I have tried Transferring the vertex groups using 
Source layers selection>by name. 
Destination Layers material>all layers. 
and mix mode> Mix/Replace.

but its not working the way i expected it to. I'm guessing I'm not understanding how this tool works, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

TL:DR is there a way for me to get the intersecting vertices to have the same weight across all the meshes so they deform as if this were one solid mesh?

Ill keep trying things and looking around for other ways to accomplish my goal and if i figure it out ill be sure to post what i was able to do here.

Thanks for reading!

Edit: I should add that i have also tried making all of the meshes a single object, weighing the armature and then making the segments again and i still had the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question, It was something i had already done but didnt do it quite right.

In object mode>Select all Meshes>Join
Move to Edit mode>Select all Vertices>Vertex>Merge Vertices>By Distance

[image]

Apply Automatic Weights as normal AND THEN start seperating the parts you want to.